# What's Best Way of Formatting Decimal Numbers in Java?

Tags: java, formatting

I've been looking for formatting decimal numbers easily as in JavaScript by using `toFixed()`.

What's your suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps the [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class?

Comment: Try Googling 'formatting decimal numbers java'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using String.format is likely to be the simplest.

```
var num = new Number(13.3714);
document.write(num.toFixed()+"<br />");
document.write(num.toFixed(1)+"<br />");
document.write(num.toFixed(3)+"<br />");
document.write(num.toFixed(10));
```

in Java

```
double num = 13.3714;
// Uses String.format()
System.out.printf(
          "%f<br />" +
          "%.1f<br />" +
          "%.3f<br />" +
          "%.10f<br />", num, num, num, num);
```

Comment: I guess, this was what I looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Did you take a look at the [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class?? There are a number of `scale` related functions that might do what you need.

Comment: @Gevorg sorry to upset you day. :(

Comment: @PeterLawrey what kind of sorcery is that? It doesn't even look like java to me! By the way, you could at least vote me up if you really feel sorry :p

Comment: @Gevorg I just preferred more detail answer, isn't it fair? Anyway, sorry.

Comment: @Ogulcan it's not fair on a Friday!

Answer (score 2):

Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for anything decimal related in Java.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Way Depends Upon Requirement**

1. Using the format() method

> specifies the format "%.3f" denotes 3 decimal places
> "%.4f" denotes 4 decimal
>
> ```
> for Example  Double d = 32345.123214;
> System.out.format("%.2f", d);//output 32345.12
> ```

2. String.format

> Double x = 4.0; System.out.println(String.format("%.5f", x));
> //output4.00000

3.**DecimalFormat**
DecimalFormat class has various format options to round up the decimal places
based on the initialized format. In the below example, we have initialized the
DecimalFormat with the format as "#.##". This means it limits the decimal place up
to 2 digits

```
 Double d = 1234.67538911;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    
    System.out.println("Using DecimalForamt: " + df.format(d));//output 1234.67
```

4.Using Math.round()

The Math.round() method is another method to limit the decimal places in Java. If we want to round a number to 1 decimal place, then we multiply and divide the input number by 10.0 in the round() method. Similarly, for 2 decimal places, we can use 100.0, for 3 decimal places, we can use 1000.0, and so on.

```
Double n = 123.4567;
    System.out.println("Original value: " + n);
    
    Double d = (double) (Math.round(n*10.0)/10.0);
    System.out.println(d);
    
    d = (double) (Math.round(n*100.0)/100.0);
    System.out.println(d);
    
    d = (double) (Math.round(n*1000.0)/1000.0);
    System.out.println(d);


Original value: 123.4567
123.5
123.46
123.457
```

5 .Using apache commons library
apache-commons math3 library contains a Precision class method round()

```
 Double d = 456.98234;
    
    Double n = Precision.round(d,2);
```

to add library

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```